# How to merge 2 dataframes and fill blank spaces with previous dataframe values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two datasets like the following:

df1:

| gene_id | pvalue |
| --- | --- |
| ENSG00000000003 | 0.04 |
| ENSG00000000419 | 0.004 |
| ENSG00000111780 | 0.0004 |
| ENSG00000093100 | 0.00004 |

df2:

| gene_id | gene_name |
| --- | --- |
| ENSG00000000003 | TSPAN6 |
| ENSG00000000419 | DPM1 |
| ENSG00000111780 |  |
| ENSG00000093100 |  |

I want to join the two dataframes by the gene_id column and fill the gene_name blanks with the corresponding gene_id.

The result I would like to obtain is as follows:

| gene_id | pvalue | gene_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG00000000003 | 0.04 | TSPAN6 |
| ENSG00000000419 | 0.004 | DPM1 |
| ENSG00000111780 | 0.0004 | ENSG00000111780 |
| ENSG00000093100 | 0.00004 | ENSG00000093100 |

How could I get the above result in R preferably using dplyr (or tidyverse)?

I tried to use left_join, but in gene_name there are blank spaces not filled.

```
new_df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "gene_id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do the join just use this. It will check for the empty values and place the `gene_id` for that row in `gene_name`:

```
new_df$gene_name <- ifelse(df$gene_name == '',df$gene_id,df$gene_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Tidyverse solution:
We can use  `coalesce` after replacing empty characters with NAs, or we can use `replace`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "gene_id") %>%
    mutate(gene_name = na_if(gene_name, "")) %>%
    mutate(gene_name = coalesce(gene_name, gene_id)

#or

left_join(df1, df2, by = "gene_id") %>%
    mutate(gene_name = replace(gene_name,
                         gene_name == "",
                         gene_id[gene_name == ""]
                         )
           )
```

example data

```
df  <- tibble(id = paste0("some_string_",1:3), dat = c("bob", "mike", ""))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  id            dat   
  <chr>         <chr> 
1 some_string_1 "bob" 
2 some_string_2 "mike"
3 some_string_3 ""
```

Example solution

```
df %>% 
    mutate(dat = na_if(dat, "")) %>% 
    mutate(dat = coalesce(dat, as.character(id)))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  id            dat          
  <chr>         <chr>        
1 some_string_1 bob          
2 some_string_2 mike         
3 some_string_3 some_string_3
```